# update query reducing a column value by 2 each time

Tags: sql, vb.net

Here i have created an sql statement to update a column value reduced by one each time.But whenever i run the query it is getting reduced by two.What might be the reason for this

```
UPDATE       books
SET          no_of_copies = no_of_copies - 1
WHERE        (title = ?)
```

Here is the visual basic code

```
    Private Sub issue_from_listbox2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles issue_from_listbox2.Click


               If (Me.Book_studentTableAdapter1.studentBorrowHistory(uniqueId) < 5) Then


                Dim bookID = Me.BooksTableAdapter.getSelectedBookID(ListBox2.SelectedItem)
                Me.Book_studentTableAdapter1.IssueBookToStudent(bookID, uniqueId)
                Me.BooksTableAdapter.updateBookTable(ListBox2.SelectedItem)

                DataGridView2.Rows.Add(ListBox2.SelectedItem)
                DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()



            Else
                MessageBox.Show("your shelf is full")

            End If
        End Sub
```

Comment: Very odd. Any triggers?

Comment: @jarlh: interesting link: oddity <-> trigger

Comment: perhaps the query runs twice? we need some more context here.

Comment: Without more information, it's impossible to know. It might be your update called twice ( in a loop ?) or a trigger.

Comment: it is inside a button click event .after clicking the button the query runs

Comment: It might be a good idea to post the code behind your button click that is actually making this call. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i have posted the code

Comment: Postback??? Is this asp;net or winforms

Comment: this is windows web forms

Comment: I suspect that `Me.Book_studentTableAdapter1.IssueBookToStudent(bookID, uniqueId)` does the same job (`no_of_copies = no_of_copies - 1`).

Comment: @AlexKudryashev  i created a data macro which will reduce no_ of_copies whenever new row is created .I totally forgot about that..Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @AlexKudryashev You should post it as answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that `Me.Book_studentTableAdapter1.IssueBookToStudent(bookID, uniqueId)` does the same job `(no_of_copies = no_of_copies - 1)`.